# Vertical Megamenu Navbar for Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a few vertical menus in the past on bootstrap using the dropdown-menu compontent. To make it a megamenu I would have to specify a specific width for the submenu to flyout to - a definitive width. This is because the vertical width(parent) is too small.

The problem is the content is dynamic, so it would be good to have this width flexible - by using %'s, as at the moment we have to mould the content to fit the menu. If I add the col-lg-12 class to the submenu it will only be 100% of its parent width (the vertical width), I can't increase the vertical width as this would span across the page.

I want something like this - http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

However, the yamm3 example is a horizontal nav, therefore the parent is already spanning across the page to give the submenu a huge range to add whatever col-lg-?? it likes.

Does anybody know how to turn the Yamm3 example into a vertical navbar but keeping the flexible mega-submenu width without being restricted by its parent?

Comment: https://1.s3.envato.com/files/85213408/Screenshots/img3.png is this kinda what you are looking for?

Comment: That's strange, I was just on that screenshot - Yes its what I am looking for however I'm hesitant in downloading another set of markup/files. Ideally I want this to work with Bootstrap - here is a bootply of my markup http://www.bootply.com/59uB8TRLro